# Why does dom.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue print the text inside the root tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, minidom

**library.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<library>library-text. :D
    <book isbn="1111111111">
        <title lang="en">T1 T1 T1 T1 T1</title>
        <date>2001</date>
        <author>A1 A1 A1 A1 A1</author>     
        <price>10.00</price>
    </book>
    <book isbn="2222222222">
        <title lang="en">T2 T2 T2 T2 T2</title>
        <date>2002</date>
        <author>A2 A2 A2 A2 A2</author>     
        <price>20.00</price>
    </book>
    <book isbn="3333333333">
        <title lang="en">T3 T3 T3 T3</title>
        <date>2003</date>
        <author>A3 A3 A3 A3 A3y</author>        
        <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
</library>
```

**Python code**

```
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom

xml_fname = "library.xml"

dom = minidom.parse(xml_fname) 

print(dom.firstChild.tagName)
print(dom.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue)
```

**Output**

```
library
library-text. :D
```

Why does `dom.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue` print the text inside the root tag?

Shouldn't it have been `dom.firstChild.nodeValue`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodes in the DOM do not only represent elements, text values are *also* nodes. The first child node inside the `<library>` element is a text node, and it's value is the Python string `'library-text. :D\n    '`:

```py
>>> dom.firstChild.firstChild
<DOM Text node "'library-te'...">
>>> dom.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue
'library-text. :D\n    '
```

Note that the `nodeValue` property of `Element`s is *always* null (== `None` in Python); see the [DOM level 1 definition for `Node`](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-1950641247):

> In cases where there is no obvious mapping of these attributes for a specific `nodeType` (e.g., `nodeValue` for an `Element` or `attributes` for a `Comment`), this returns `null`.

What node type holds what type of value for `Node.nodeValue` is specified in the [*Definition Group NodeType* section](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-1841493061).

The DOM API is a very *bare bones, basic* API, aimed at compatibility with a very broad range of languages, and this is especially true for the DOM Level 1 specification (the only spec that `minidom` supports). You generally don't want to use it, at all, if you can possibly avoid it. In Python, use a higher-level API like the [ElementTree API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) (use the [`lxml` library](https://lxml.de/), which is a more feature-rich compatible implementation).

Using ElementTree, you deal primarily with *just* elements, and text is accessible via the `text` and `tail` attribute on elements.

Comment: `firstChild` is the root. The text is inside the root. So, why `dom.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue` ?

Comment: @user366312: because text nodes are nodes too.

Comment: ` text values are also nodes` --- how? Then how would you interpret `<root>text0<tag1>text1</tag1></root>` ? Is `text1` considered as a node here?

Comment: @user366312: yes.

Comment: @user366312: in the DOM API, there are a whole range of subclasses of the `Node` type. Elements and Text are just two of the possible node types. Text is not an attribute of elements, it is a separate node type, and so are comments, and processing instructions. See the [specification overview](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/#core-ID-1590626202).